# Why does a TextReader complain when file is opened by another process?

Tags: c#, file, file-io

See simple unit test example below

```
[Test]
public void TextReaderRequiresWriteAccessToFile()
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(Folder, "Texts.txt")))
    {
    }
}
```

This test fails when I open the text file in an editor. I'd expect that the file would be opened with read privileges by `File.OpenText`.

> System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\*a location to a folder*\Texts.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Is there a reason why .NET requires extra privileges to open a file for read via this API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, but it does only require read privileges.

The problem is that the editor prevents even read access (in .NET, that would be `FileShare.None` - the default for write access). If you opened the file using `OpenText` in both cases, rather than using the editor, it would work just fine. So you probably want an editor that doesn't lock the file (for example, Visual Studio).

It's not a problem of .NET - the editor prohibits you from opening the file for reading altogether. You might want to read up on sharing file access a bit.

Comment: Ahhhh that explains it. I was completely looking in the wrong direction! Thanks for the answer! (Since the actual code is executed at build time and generates obscure errors I'll just copy the file to another location). Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, just wondering. The "other" application in this case is Excel. Why does my test complain about file being in use by another process, while I can simply open the file in Excel and afterwards open the file in notepad? If notepad can open the file, then I should be able to open the file in my program, right?

Comment: @bas Hah, yeah, I half-expected Excel to be the one, that's what I'm running into all the time too :) Do try `FileShare.ReadWrite` as suggested by Nico, that's definitely required if someone has the file open for writing - if they're using at least `FileShare.Read` too, it should work fine (if not, you're out of luck, more or less). That's probably what Notepad does. If that doesn't help, then I guess Notepad might be using something like a shadow copy, but it doesn't seem likely...

Comment: :). Yeah tried all `FileShare` combinations without luck. I'll go for the shadow copy. Thanks for the guidance ! (yours and @NicoSchuele)

Comment: Got the same problem and resolved it according to @Luaan's suggestions.  In my app, it is a log file (from log4net).  Notepad opens it fine, but other programs using `OpenText` can't.  I changed the `OpenText` call to `new StreamReader(File.Open(path,  FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), Encoding.UTF8)` and it now opens fine.  I suspect that `OpenText` simply doesn't give the open command enough privileges.

Answer (score 2):

When your file is open in a text editor, it has a handle open to it. That means, you need to explicitly open your file with `FileShare.Read`. This way, you'll get Read access while the file is already open in Read/Write mode somewhere else.

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(Folder, "Texts.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
}
```

Comment: Hmm, what I understand from Luaan is that "the other editor" should've opened the file with FileShare.Read. Since it didn't, there is nothing I can do. I tried your suggestion anyway, but it indeed seems to fail with the same exception.

Comment: Correct. In that scenario, you can only hope that the "other editor" doesn't open the file exclusively. Still, you could try `FileShare.ReadWrite`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, [`File.OpenText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext) does not accept `FileMode`, `FileAccess`, or `FileShare` arguments.